# Proof of Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, ed. 8, #7.522.1

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, integration

Looking for a proof to formula 7.522.1 in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik (8th edition) which states
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}x^{\gamma-1}{_{2}F_1}(\alpha,\beta;\delta;-x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\Gamma(\delta)\lambda^{-\gamma}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}E(\alpha\,;\beta:\gamma\,;\delta:\lambda),
\end{equation}
for $\Re \lambda>0$ and $\Re \gamma>0$ where $E(p\,;\alpha_{r}:q\,;\varrho_{s}:x)$ is the [MacRobert E-Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacRobert_E_function).

> **Update 4/13/18**
>
> [This](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.26.0004.01) gets it started:
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}x^{\gamma-1}{_{2}F_1}(\alpha,\beta;\delta;-x)\,\mathrm{d}x
> =\frac{\Gamma(\delta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\gamma-1}e^{-\lambda x}G^{1,2}_{2,2}\left(x\,\bigg|{1-\alpha,1-\beta \atop 0,1-\delta}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.
> \end{equation}
>   This is in the form of formula 7.813.1 in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik (8th edition). If all the conditions are met (and there are a lot of them) then
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda x}x^{\gamma-1}{_{2}F_1}(\alpha,\beta;\delta;-x)\,\mathrm{d}x
> =\frac{\Gamma(\delta)\lambda^{-\gamma}}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}
> G^{1,3}_{3,2}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\,\bigg|{1-\gamma,1-\alpha,1-\beta \atop 0,1-\delta}\right).
> \end{equation}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have copied 7.522.1 incorrectly. In the 7th edition of G&R, the rhs is
$$\frac {\Gamma(\delta) \lambda^{-\gamma}} {\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)}
E(\alpha, \beta, \gamma : \delta : \lambda).$$
Then, using the formula for the relation of the E-function with the G-function and the reflection formula for the G-function,
$$E(\alpha, \beta, \gamma : \delta : \lambda) =
G_{2,3}^{3,1} \left( \lambda \middle|
 {1, \delta \atop \alpha, \beta, \gamma} \right) =
G_{3,2}^{1,3} \left( \frac 1 \lambda \middle |
{1 - \alpha, 1 - \beta, 1 - \gamma \atop 0, 1 - \delta} \right),$$
in agreement with 7.813.1.

This is a special case of the general formula for the integral of $x^p$ times a product of two linear G-functions.

Comment: I have the 8th edition of G&R and it does in fact read $E(\alpha;\beta:\gamma;\delta:\lambda)$.  I will report the error to the editor.

Comment: Can you please provide your reference for the $E$ to $G$ conversion? Thanks.

Comment: I took the conversion formula from the Wikipedia link that you provided.